# Deleting specific line numbers in ed in a single command

Tags: ed

In `ed` one can delete a line number by typing its address followed by the `delete` command, as in `1d`. To delete a range of lines, one uses the comma, as in `1,4d`. One can also delete lines with specific content as in `g/Ted/d`. Is there a way to specify the deletion of non-sequential lines *in a single command*? I.e. let's say I wanted to delete lines 1 and 3 and 8 at one time without typing:

```
1d
3d
8d
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with `ed` (an editor from the 60s), no. But with `ex` (in case you're ready  to venture into the 70s or later), or rather the `vim` implementation of `ex` (90s), you can do:

```
g/\v%1l|%3l|%8l/d
```

Where [`\%nl`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25l) (simplified to `%nl` with `\v`) is a regexp operator that matches wherever the current line is the *n*<sup>th</sup>.

Note that with the approach that runs `1d`, `3d`, `8d` in sequence, after `1d` what used to be the third line is now the second, so you'd end up deleting the 1<sup>st</sup>, 4<sup>th</sup> and 10<sup>th</sup> lines. You don't have that problem if you start from the end: `8d`, `3d`, `1d`.

Comment: Could you add a link to where is that entry in the manual ? Cant find it anywhere.

Comment: @QuartzCristal, try `:h %l`

Comment: Ahhhh, http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\%l